# Creating a Collaborative Chart Editing Template with Cell Modification Tracking in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two different requirements for this project:

1. I want to have a spreadsheet that's used as a template, where people can edit the chart. Within this requirement is that two users can fill out the chart at the same time and not overwrite each other's work (and they also shouldn't see each other).
2. After some form of submitting the spreadsheet, make it that every cell that's subsequently edited has the background change colors, so that it's evident that the cell was modified.

(As a side point, it was requested that user's should not have to deal with authorizing a script to run, which I took to mean that I'm only left to deal with published web apps UNLESS someone knows a way to create a new sheet and programmatically give it authorization to run a script. Even if you could figure that out, I'm not sure it'll help, I would still need to get around the problem of adding a newly created sheet's ID to the script's triggers, as I spell out below).

For number 1, my thought was to make a web app that would duplicate the main template and give the user a new copy, here's my code for that:

```
  const d = new Date();
  const fileName = `Created: ${formatDate(d)}`;
  console.log(fileName);   

  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID");
  const newID = DriveApp.getFileById("ID").makeCopy(fileName, destFolder).getId();

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(newID);
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  
  const url = (`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${newID}/edit`);

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>window.location.href="' + url + '";</script>');
}

function formatDate(date) {
  let options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false
  };

  return date.toLocaleString('en-US', options).replaceAll("/", "-").replaceAll(":", "-").replaceAll(", ", "-");
}
```

My problem is, I'm now stuck. I can't think of a way to accomplish number 2. I had any idea to create a unbound apps script that had an onEdit trigger, which would run like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.oldValue && e.value && e.oldValue !== e.value){
    e.range.setBackground('red');
  }
}
```

But I would need to add a new trigger for every new sheet created, which is cumbersome, but also, apps scripts only allows for 25 triggers max. I thought of a ridiculous system where a script will copy itself when the triggers are close to maxing out, but that seems very inelegant. Does anyone have any better ideas of how I can pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, the way I solved this was by deploying the code below as a web app. If anyone has any comments, suggestions, or ideas of a better way to accomplish this, I would love to hear.

```
function doGet() {
  const d = new Date();
  const fileName = `Created: ${formatDate(d)}`;
  console.log(fileName);   

  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById([ID removed]);
  const newID = DriveApp.getFileById([ID removed]).makeCopy(fileName, destFolder).getId();

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(newID);
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
  
  const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${newID}/edit`;

  const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Emergency Department Assignment Sheet</title>
    <script>
    var formSubmitted = false;
      function submitForm() {
        var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(date) {
          if (!date) {  
            alert("Please enter the date in cell B2 before submitting. Make sure press the Enter button after entering the date.");
          } else {
            submitButton.value = "Submit Successful!";
            submitButton.disabled = true;
            google.script.run.addConditionalFormatting(date, '${newID}', '${url}');
            formSubmitted = true;
          }
        }).getCellValue('${newID}', 'B2');
      }  

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
          exitPage(event);
        });

        function exitPage(event) {
          if (!formSubmitted) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = 'Are you sure? If you leave without submitting, your data will be lost!';

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
              if (response && response.deleted) {
                console.log("Sheet Deleted!");
              } else {
                console.log("Sheet Deletion Failed!");
              }
            }).deleteSheet('${newID}', '${fileName}');
          }
        }
    </script>

    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 95%;
        border: none;
      }

      #submit-button {
        background-color: #008000; /* Set the background color */
        color: #FFFFFF; /* Set the text color */
        padding: 10px 20px; /* Set padding for the button */
        font-size: 16px; /* Set the font size */
        border: none; /* Remove the button border */
        cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer cursor on hover */
      }

      #submit-button:hover {
        background-color: #006400; /* Change the background color on hover */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="${url}" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
    <form>      
      <input id="submit-button" type="button" value="Click here to submit" onclick="submitForm()">
    </form>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('unload', exitPage);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>`

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}

function addConditionalFormatting(date, newID, url) {
  var dORn = ""; 
  date[0] == 0 ? dORn = "Day" : dORn = "Night";
  console.log("dORn: " + dORn);
  let fileName = `${date[1]} - ${dORn}`;  
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newID);
  spreadsheet.rename(fileName);
  console.log(`Renamed file to "${fileName}`);
  const sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  date = new Date(date[1]);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  const range = sheets[i].getRange("A1:E46");
  var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var rules = [];
  
  for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < values[row].length; col++) {
      var cellValue = values[row][col];
      var cell = sheets[i].getRange(row + 1, col + 1);
      var rule;

      if (cell.getA1Notation() === "B2") {
      // Rule for cell B2
      rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
        .whenFormulaSatisfied(`=B2 <> date(${date.getFullYear()}, ${date.getMonth() + 1}, ${date.getDate()})`)
        .setFontColor('#FF0000')
        .setRanges([cell])
        .build();
    } else {
      // Rules for other cells
      if (cellValue === '' || cellValue === undefined) {
        rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .whenFormulaSatisfied(`=ISBLANK(${cell.getA1Notation()}) = FALSE`)
          .setFontColor('#FF0000')
          .setRanges([cell])
          .build();
      } else {
        rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .whenFormulaSatisfied(`=${cell.getA1Notation()} <> "${cellValue}"`)
          .setFontColor('#FF0000')
          .setRanges([cell])
          .build();
      }
    }
      rules.push(rule);   
    } //col loop (inner)
  } //row loop (outer) 
  sheets[i].setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  } //sheet loop
  console.log("Set conditional formatting");
  sendEmail(url, fileName);
} //end function

function getCellValue(sheetId, cell) {
  var value = "";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
   value = sheets[i].getRange(cell).getDisplayValue();
     if (value !== "" && value !== undefined) {
      value = [i, value];
      break;
    }
  }
  return value;
}

function sendEmail(sheetUrl, subject) {  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "[Email removed]",
    subject: subject,
    body: "Please find the link to the Google Sheet: " + sheetUrl
  });
  console.log("Sent Email!");
}

function deleteSheet(id, fileName) {
  try {
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
    console.log(`Sent "${fileName}" to the trash`);
    return { deleted: true };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return { deleted: false }; 
  }
}

function formatDate(date) {
  let options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: false
  };

  return date.toLocaleString('en-US', options).replaceAll("/", "-").replaceAll(":", "-").replaceAll(", ", "-");
}
```